# Only one Route 53 Health Check for multiple targets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

We are in a process of migrating a domain name to AWS Route 53 and, to simplify it, need to DNS load-balance one domain name to 500 IPs. Say, `example.com` with 500 possible values of:

- `A 50.70.61.1`
- `A 50.70.61.2`
- `A 50.70.61.3`
- ...

We also need to have health checks for obvious reasons.
In this case, we not only need to create 500 `A` records in the DNS zone, but also 500 health checks that match each of the `A` records.

With our previous DNS provider it was possible to create only one generic health checks and the IP of each target is used when checking health.

Anyone aware of a way to do this in AWS?